# How to filter by a column generated in the same query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The below is a very simple query where `my_data` consists only of 1 row, and it's there only to help me explain my issue better.

```
WITH

    my_data AS(
    SELECT
        TIMESTAMP("2020-02-11 13:15:00 UTC") AS my_timestamp
        ,50 AS my_customers)

SELECT
    DATE(my_timestamp) AS my_date
    ,my_customers
FROM
    my_data
WHERE
    my_date = "2020-02-11"
```

This won't run in Google Big Query's standard SQL, although I recall running something similar in the past. The reason it won't run is that it doesn't know what my_date is, and my guess is because it's getting created in the same query.

My question is:

1. Can I filter by a new generated column, that was generated in the same query and doesn't exist in my table(`my_data`)?
2. Is this the right way or is this a bad practise?

A workaround would be to just create `my_data` first without that filter but with the extra column `my_date` and filter it later by going through it again.

Thanks

Comment: No, you cannot filter in a `WHERE` for an alias defined in the `SELECT`.  Use a CTE, subquery, or repeat the expression.

Comment: Change the `WHERE` to `HAVING`

Comment: @mattyx17 I just tried `HAVING`, but it requires all fields to be `GROUP BY`ed, essentially killing all duplicate rows. Unless I am doing something wrong. It fills like a risky workaround. @Gordon Linoff, if that's all can you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to start answering your question as you presented them.

1. No, you cannot filter by a new generated column alias you just create in the select statement and I will explain why, later.
2. On the other hand, you are right on using a CLE (the part that start with WITH) in order to filter data in a subsequent SELECT. The problem is that you are referencing the wrong thing.

On the first part, you just created a new table named **"my_data"** and that table contain two columns: **my_timestamp** and **my_customer**. You can subsequently query that table and filter by the timestamp, the only thing is that you cannot use the alias you created in a SELECT statement in the WHERE clause. That is because *there is a certain order in which SQL operators run.*

In this case, you are using the alias **"my_date"** in the where clause but the **WHERE** is processed before the **SELECT** clause, so, the **WHERE** clause does not knows what **"my_date"** is and for that's the reason you are receiving that error regarding "my_date".

I am not sure about parsing in BigQuery, never use it before, but assuming your parsing with the dates is correct. The only change your query would need would be to *change **"my-date"** in the where clause by **DATE(my_timestamp)***

```
WITH
  my_data AS(
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP("2020-02-11 13:15:00 UTC") AS my_timestamp,
    50 AS my_customers)
SELECT
  DATE(my_timestamp) AS my_date,
  my_customers
FROM
  my_data
WHERE
  DATE(my_timestamp) = "2020-02-11"
```

Find below the SQL Order of Operation I was mentioning before. It is always critical to consider this when designing queries.

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY

Hope this help.

Comment: I see. Great explanation. I wasn't familiar with the SQL Order of Operation. It makes sense.

Comment: I was not either. That thing drove me crazy for a long time til I realized and studied the order of operations. I believe at the beginning is very intuitive to think the WHERE should be able to filter by whatever we are using on the SELECT. Hopefully we now know that is not how SQL works. Glad this help my friend. Regards,

Comment: Hey, just found this awesome link by chartio where they explain the order of sql query. I believe this may help. https://dataschool.com/sql-optimization/order-of-a-sql-query/

Answer (score 1):

Below "trick" is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH

    my_data AS(
    SELECT
        TIMESTAMP("2020-02-11 13:15:00 UTC") AS my_timestamp
        ,50 AS my_customers)

SELECT
    my_date
    ,my_customers
FROM
    my_data,
UNNEST([DATE(my_timestamp)]) AS my_date    
WHERE
    my_date = "2020-02-11"
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to duplicate function you already using?

```
WITH
  my_data AS(
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP("2020-02-11 13:15:00 UTC") AS my_timestamp,
    50 AS my_customers)
SELECT
  DATE(my_timestamp) AS my_date,
  my_customers
FROM
  my_data
WHERE
  DATE(my_timestamp) = "2020-02-11"
```